# Missing parameter name in MongoDB repository causing MappingException

Tags: spring-boot, docker, native

I am in the process of converting my Spring Boot application to a native image using Spring Native and GraalVM. My application uses MongoDB, and I am encountering a `MappingException` when the application attempts to interact with the database through the repository layer.

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@bf07bd2a does not have a name] with root cause

**What I've tried:**

- Registering my document classes and repositories in the `RuntimeHintsRegistrar` implementation, but this has not resolved the issue.
- Using the GraalVM native image agent to generate reflection configuration, but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue ?

Comment: @antoine.lange yes I did, I have just posted the answer

Comment: @antoine.lange please vote the answer if helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved a MappingException in my Spring Boot application (converted to a native image with Spring Native and GraalVM) by adding a compiler argument in the Gradle build script. This change ensured that parameter names are available at runtime, which is necessary for correct operation of frameworks that rely on parameter names for mapping purposes (like Spring Data).

Here's the specific change I made in build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            ...
            options.compilerArgs << '-parameters' // Adding this line
        }
    }
}
```

The options.compilerArgs << '-parameters' line adds a compiler argument to include debug information about method parameter names in the compiled bytecode. This is crucial for the Spring framework, as it needs to know the names of method parameters (especially in controller methods and repositories) for proper binding and processing. By default, Java does not store formal parameter names in the compiled bytecode, so adding this compiler argument is necessary to preserve them, which in turn resolves the MappingException related to parameter name mapping in Spring Boot applications compiled with GraalVM for native images.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the same issue but with kotlin project. Everything works with Spring 3.1.x, but started from 3.2.0 got the same error and 'name' field is exactly null. What was broken in new spring is not clear to me. But I'm using standard runtime with JVM. So its probably extends no only to GraalVM

Comment: We had the same case. @Dasma's answer worked for us - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77627076/1760058. We instructed the compiler to persist the parameter's names and the problem was fixed.
For some reason upgrading to Spring 3.2.0 makes parameter names disappear at runtime and Spring Data can not properly construct derived queries.