# spring-boot-starter-data-redis "data.mapping.Parameter does not have a name error" when upgrade spring boot from 3.1 to 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

After updating Spring Boot from 3.1 to 3.2, I followed the instructions to add the -parameters flag for Java compilation. Despite this, I'm still encountering the same error, indicated by the stack trace I received.

```
**org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@57ced0b5 does not have a name**
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:301)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:273)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.doReadInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:222)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.readInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:180)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingRedisConverter.java:818)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.readProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:284)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$ConverterAwareParameterValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingRedisConverter.java:1092)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$ConverterAwareParameterValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingRedisConverter.java:1075)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:71)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:301)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:273)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.doReadInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:222)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.read(MappingRedisConverter.java:174)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.read(MappingRedisConverter.java:105)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.get(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.getAllOf(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:374)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.getAllOf(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:341)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$findAll$2(KeyValueTemplate.java:216)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:314)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.executeRequired(KeyValueTemplate.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.findAll(KeyValueTemplate.java:214)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.findAll(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:108)
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.findAll(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:42)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)
**at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy157.findAll(Unknown Source)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @AllArgsConstructor or @RequiredArgsConstructor on the POJO which is giving this error. It should be resolved then.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using `@AllArgsConstructor` as suggested, since `@RequiredArgsConstructor` conflicts with `@Builder` in my case. However, I'm still facing issues

Comment: I used the combination of `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` on my POJO and it resolved the issue. `@AllArgsConstructor` alone was still throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Data update causes this exception due to [parameter name retention](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention): "... code within the Spring Framework and Spring portfolio frameworks no longer attempts to deduce parameter names by parsing bytecode".

Adding a `@NoArgsConstructor` can be the first way to solve because "...If an entity contains a field of some type which is defined in another package, a mapping exception will be thrown during a read operation if said object doesn't provide an empty constructor (private, protected or public)" ([Spring Data MongoDb issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4615)).

If there is no opportunity to do that, you can add compiler argument (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427865/missing-parameter-name-in-mongodb-repository-causing-mappingexception)). However, there is a certain risk of exposing sensible information using this approach, for details see [this case study](https://ricma.co/posts/tech/dev/migrating-to-spring-61-javac-parameters/).